# How can I make content disappear when a user logs in?

Tags: plugins, php, css, javascript, login

I am working in Wordpress, and I would like to make certain elements disappear once a user logs in. How can I do this?

I have social icons on my page that I positioned to the center of my menu bar at the top of my website. 
those icons are generated by a plugin

that is what i want to disappear

https://hughesjobs.net

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a PHP if statement in combination with [`is_user_logged_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

If you're editing your header try this:

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
// Your social media icons code goes here
<?php } ?>
```

The exclamation point before `is_user_logged_in()` means 'is not' in PHP, so your code essentially says, "If the user is not logged in, show the code between the brackets".

Comment: how exactly would i code my social-icons in to that function?

Comment: It depends on how you're generating them. How are the social icons currently being generated?

Comment: through a plugin..... through wordpress .... but if you are willing i would need an exact emaple of how to code this

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize that piece. In that case you're in a tough spot. If the plugin doesn't come with the option to hide them from logged in users, you'll have to edit the code of the plugin itself, which is less than ideal, since any time you update the plugin it'll overwrite your customization.

Comment: Since I'm not sure exactly how your theme and plugin work together, here's a quick and dirty hint to point you in the right direction. Find this (probably in header.php):
`<div class="row grid-row">

<!-- Widgetizer | Section Template -->`
Paste this after the DIV `<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) { ?>` then find the closing DIV tag and paste this right before it: `<?php } ?>`. That's the best I can do. Good luck!

Comment: i dont get it...may i have an example

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `functions.php`

```
function remove_social_to_logged_users() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $remove_icons =" <style>
                         section#widgetizerupv91rw {
                            display: none;
                         }
                         </style> ";

        echo $remove_icons; 
    } 
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_social_to_logged_users' );
```

I check your website and get the id of the social icons. I'm willing to help you to add this in your website if you like.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, can you explain what this code does and how it helps the OP :)

Comment: Like `is_user_logged_in` is a WordPress function which helps to determine whether a user is logged in or not based on that we are adding custom css to the head of the site to set particular section to not display

Comment: Also I say this is not an ideal solution as we are just using CSS to set the appearance.

Comment: The wp_head action hook is triggered within the <head></head>.

Comment: Please read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Comment: Thanks, I know that, what I'm suggesting you is to add that explanation in your answer so that it will be more helpful for the users.

Comment: Sorry, I just join to this community a few hours ago. Trying to help :D

Comment: Great to see you around, thanks for helping :) No need to be sorry we learn along the way.